# How to pass js argument into css style

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm creating a web service with Angular and Spring Boot and I'm using cdkDrag to place some images around the workspace. I want to keep the images on the same places after refreshing browser. After every drag and drop, I'm saving every image coordinates in the database. When I refresh the browser, I have previous coordinates storaged in Router class:

```
export class Router implements Node {

  id: string;

  x: number;
  y: number;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Some html:

```
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <a *ngFor="let router of routers">
      <img id="node" src="assets/images/router.png" cdkDrag (click)="updateParameters($event, router)">
    </a>
  </mat-sidenav-content>'
```

And here, I want to set margin-left as router.x + "px" and margin-top as router.y. Is it possible? I tried `style="margin-left: {{router.x}}px"` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

> An attribute directive that updates styles for the containing HTML element. Sets one or more style properties, specified as colon-separated key-value pairs. The key is a style name, with an optional . suffix (such as 'top.px', 'font-style.em'). The value is an expression to be evaluated. The resulting non-null value, expressed in the given unit, is assigned to the given style property. If the result of evaluation is null, the corresponding style is removed.

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': router.x + 'px'}">...</some-element>
```